# Ensure a field is unique across all collection objects

Tags: meteor

I want to ensure that `username` field of `Users` collection is unique. In other words, there cannot be duplicate usernames. Does meteor support such feature out of box or should I do some validation before inserting/updating a user object?

Answer (score 0):

Given [this line of code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/0e3c992fd8f178efd9e832038257ae36cec90351/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1027), Meteor supports it out of the box.

Comment: Yea I think it checks when inserting a user, but it doesn't check when I update the username field like `      Meteor.users.update(Meteor.user()._id,
        {$set: {'username': newUsername}}
      )`

Comment: I see that `Meteor.users._ensureIndex('username', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});` prevents duplicate usernames when creating a new user object, but how do I prevent it when updating?

Comment: If `Meteor.users.insert` throws an `duplicate key error` exception for the username field, I'm quite confident that `Meteor.users.update` will too.

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't, unfortunately. Must I be doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but I find that surprising. How did you do the update? Did you do something like `Meteor.users.update('a-user-id', {$set: {username: "a-username-another-user-has"}})`

Answer (score 0):

You must check if username is unique by running a function like below

`userExists = function(username) {
  return !!Meteor.users.findOne({username: username});
}`

Meteor only checks uniqueness when inserting a new document into a collection.